Nginx basic_auth is skipped and login prompt not shown due to redirect loop
I have the following .conf file for nginx. I am configuring authentication along with a cookie.
When I enter the url of the login page, it doesn't show the prompt for entering credentials, and goes into an infinite redirection loop.
I thought I could separate the redirection logic to another block, but I can't find a way to jump to the /login/redirection block.
I tried using try_files, but it didn't work.
What can I do to make sure the login prompt always appear?
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # Check if the user is authenticated by looking for the cookie
        if ($http_cookie !~ 'openhab_cookie=loggedin') {
            # Redirect to the login page if not authenticated
            return 302 http://localhost:81/login;
        }

        # If the user is authenticated, proceed to the application
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name localhost;

    location /login {
        # authentication (issue in here, it is skipped)
        auth_basic "Login Required";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # Only set cookie if authenticated
        if ($http_cookie !~* "openhab_cookie=loggedin") {
            add_header Set-Cookie "openhab_cookie=loggedin; Max-Age=300; Path=/; HttpOnly";
        }

        return 302 http://localhost:80/;
    }

}

Rewrite module directives (if and return) are executed before auth_basic.

@AlexeyTen that's what I am trying to solve, why the auth_basic is skipped?

It's not "skipped". Nginx's config is not a «program» that executes from up to down, it's a set of directives and they affect request processing at their phases. And phase for rewrite (NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE) goes earlier than phase for auth (NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE).

You could use try_files "hack" to make an internal redirect that will be executed after checking authorization.
location /login {
    # authentication (issue in here, it is skipped)
    auth_basic "Login Required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    try_files NON_EXISTENT @login;
}

location @login {
    # Only set cookie if authenticated
    if ($cookie_openhab_cookie != "loggedin") {
        add_header Set-Cookie "openhab_cookie=loggedin; Max-Age=300; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    }

    return 302 http://localhost:80/;
}


I did try this approach, but I got this error page after I entered my credentials and didn't redirect me:
An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please try again later. If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details. Faithfully yours, nginx.

@LaithBudairi, please, check and show nginx's error log.

here is the log:
2024/08/24 19:19:23 [notice] 16736#12560: signal process started
2024/08/24 19:20:35 [crit] 21644#2608: *2872 CreateFile() "C:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2024/08/24 19:20:35 [crit] 21644#2608: *2873 CreateFile() "C:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/login"

@LaithBudairi, nginx couldn't find your passwd file. Make sure there is a file and all paths are correct.

my passwd file is under: C:\nginx\conf , why would I have /etc directory on windows? either way it seems to be working now when I created the directories

@LaithBudairi, that's what you have written /etc/nginx/.htpasswd. Just change the path to wherever the real file is.
